# How to pass data from child to parent when a list item is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass value of the element clicked to the header component. I did that with modal provided by React-bootstrap.
The parent component (header) should receive the value of the element clicked (in child) and display in location (state). I have taken too much time on this already.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Navbar, Container, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import {
  faMapMarkerAlt, 
  faAngleDown
  } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
  import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import LocationModal from '../LocationModal/LocationModal';



export default function Header () {
    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false)
    const [location, setLocation] = useState('Lagos')
    const handleCallback = () => {
        setLocation({location})
     }
     
    return (
        <>
        <Navbar expand="lg" variant="light" bg="light">
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
                <Button variant="none" onClick={() => setModalShow(true)} className="px-2 d-inline-flex">
                    <span className="ml-1"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMapMarkerAlt} /></span>
                    <span className="ml-1">{location}</span>
                    <span className="ml-1"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} /></span>
                </Button>
                
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
        <LocationModal 
            show={modalShow}
            onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
            parentcallback={handleCallback} 
        />
        </>
    )
}
```

**Location Modal**

As you can see, I tried to write a callback function for the value obtained from child element (locationModal) so that it can be passed on and display in parent component (Header).

```
import React from 'react'
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default function LocationModal(props) {
    const locations = [
        {
            id: 1,
            location: 'Lagos'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            location: 'Abuja'
        }
    ]
   const handleClick = (value) => {
       props.parentcallback(value)
   }
    return (
      <Modal
        {...props}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton className="border-bottom-0">
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter"></Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <ul className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center list-unstyled">
              <h1>Choose Your Location</h1>
              {
                  locations.map(item => {
                      return <li 
                                className="w-75 p-2 m-2 border-1 text-white text-center bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer" 
                                key={item.id}
                                onClick={() => handleClick(item.location)}
                                value={item.location}
                                >
                                {item.location}
                            </li>
                  })
              }
          </ul>
        </Modal.Body>
    
      </Modal>
    );
  }
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: your forgot to add `location` param to your `handleCallback`

Comment: How? Do you mean I should say const handleCallback = () => {
        setLocation({location: location}) because I don't know which param to put there 
     }

Comment: `const handleCallback = (location) => { setLocation({location}) }`

Comment: Warning: Invalid value for prop `parentcallback` on <div> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at your `handleCallback` you are setting your state to be an object with `location` key, but your location state is supposed to be a string. you also are missing location param:

```
const handleCallback = () => { // you are missing location param
    setLocation({location}) // location was a string now is an object
 }
```

it should be like:

```
const handleCallback = (location) => setLocation(location)
```

but that's actually redundant, `handleCallback` does the same `setLocation` already does. Remove `handleCallback` code and just pass `setLocation` to `parentcallback`:

```
    <LocationModal 
        show={modalShow}
        onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
        parentcallback={setLocation} 
    />
```

Comment: what is the essence of this line  "const handleCallback = (location) =>  setLocation(location)". I commented it out and still working.? More also, can you teach me react context API? this is my email kiddiestvshow@gmail.com. Thank you

Comment: I don't know what you mean by essence actually. about teaching context API, it takes practice and time. react documentation already cover well its purpose https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html (text uses classes instead of hook but you can get the idea) and there are some great tutorials you can find out there.

Comment: if I get it right, I showed what would be the correct code for `handleCallback`, but then I said that's  actually not necessary to write `handleCallback` code. you can remove it altogether because you only need to pass `setLocation` down